# Sinon - spy on constructor method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I've found a couple of related questions but none seem to help with what I want to implement.

So, I would like to spy on a constructor method so that when an object created with the constructor calls this method within **a different scope** another function, I can know the arguments with which that call was made.

Example:

```
function Constructor(args){
  this.method = sinon.spy()
}

function someFunction(){
  obj = new Constructor(args);
  obj.method()
}

console.log(Constructor.method.args[0]); // list the args of the obj.method() call
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit: I realized I phrased the question wrong and ended up asking something utterly trivial :-)

Comment: I just saw what you added. It is not possible, in your `console.log(Constructor.method.args[0]);` you are using method as a static function, which it is not. Imagine what if you had 5 different Constructor instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way, you can spy over Constructor.method :

```
function Constructor(args){
    this.method = function() {}
}

const obj = new Constructor();
obj.method = sinon.spy(obj.method);
obj.method('someArg');

console.log(obj.method.args[0]);  // [ 'someArg' ]
```

But doing as you say is impossible, you cannot have a static method and a class method with the same name, and also what about if you instantiate that class more than once... Anyway the best I can come with is a solution with Proxy on constructor, like that :

```
function Constructor(args) {
    this.method = function () {}
}

const ProxyConstructor = new Proxy(Constructor, {
    construct: function (target, args, newTarget) {
        const c = new target(...args);
        const origMethod = c.method;
        c.method = function (...args) {
            ProxyConstructor.methodArgs = ProxyConstructor.methodArgs || [];
            ProxyConstructor.methodArgs = ProxyConstructor.methodArgs.concat(args)
            origMethod(...args);
        };
        return c;
    }
});


function someFunction() {
    obj = new ProxyConstructor();
    obj.method('test')
}

someFunction();
console.log(ProxyConstructor.methodArgs); // ['test']
```

You can paste that code in a file and try it. Also, sometime when writing tests, you might have to refactor your code to make it testable, or you could start by writing the tests before writing your code (TDD).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However in your example the console.log is on the same scope with the obj declaration. What I would like to do is know if the method was called even in a scope that is not accessible...